# Finding upper limit of $ab^2+bc^2+ca^2$ where $a+b+c=18$ and $(a, b, c) \in \mathbb{R^+}$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

Given $a$, $b$, $c$ are positive real numbers such that $a+b+c=18$

Prove that $$ \frac{a}{b^2+36}+\frac{b}{c^2+36}+\frac{c}{a^2+36} ≥ \frac{1}{4}$$

My progress so far :

By Sedrakyan's inequality ,
$$\dfrac{a^2}{ab^2+36a}+\dfrac{b^2}{bc^2+36b}+\dfrac{c^2}{ca^2+36c} ≥ \dfrac{(a+b+c)^2}{ab^2+bc^2+ca^2+36(a+b+c)}$$

Now I need the maximum possible value of $ab^2+bc^2+ca^2$ but I can't proceed further.

Comment: This answers your question: [Prove inequality $\frac{a}{b^2 + 1} + \frac{b}{c^2 + 1} + \frac{c}{a^2 + 1} ≤ 1.5$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/229697/prove-inequality-fracab2-1-fracbc2-1-fracca2-1-%e2%89%a4-1) (don't look at the answer but at the correction and solution added inside the question).